# SAS IF statement in transformation, I want the job to terminate

Tags: sas

I want in my code to write an IF statement which if not true will terminate the job. The transformation that the if is located is not the last transformation, it is in the middle. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The executable statement [ABORT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000230210.htm) is what you're looking for.  `ABORT ABEND` will kill SAS.  `ABORT CANCEL` will do something slightly different if you're in display manager mode; look at the documentation for more detail there.

Comment: Actually the job I have to terminate is in a Master job. So I want if my condition is not met, to end the job in order to continue to the next scheduled in the Master Job. Is that possible with abort? And without an error message??

Comment: You may need to be more specific - I don't know what a "master job" is, for example.  Is this in a particular SAS interface, like DI Studio or something like that?  Or is that a Unix/etc. concept.  `ABORT ABEND` will end as much as possible, while `ABORT CANCEL` will tend to abort just that bit.

Comment: I'm pretty new at this so I didn't know such term didn't exist :P Actually I want to schedule in DI many jobs to run sequentially. Some of the jobs if the condition is not met may need to terminate without errors. However the jobs that follow have to be completed.

Comment: It may well - I'm not a DI studio person.  If you're in DI Studio, that's a huuuuugely different beast than regular SAS.  DI Studio has (I think) the ability to have conditional links between programs; I use Enterprise Guide which I think is nearly identical.

Comment: I just started actually because I have no choice :P Thank again for the help!! :) :)

Comment: But really if you're just running the next bit, you should be okay.  If `ABORT CANCEL` issues an error (I don't know in DI Studio as I'm not there), you have other options I guess - google "Run cancel" for example.

Comment: I will try and see what happens :)

Comment: `abort` always triggers the return code of the job (%ERRORLEVEL% in Windows) to be positive. When I investigated the duplicate question, it looked like `endsas` made SAS exist with %ERRORLEVEL%=0